# How to get information from one Main Window to another Main Window after running a function PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am having trouble trying to get a file from a different window after running a function. The end goal is to get a file from one window and display the entire file on the Main Window. I have textedit set up for displaying the file. The code is below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

import analyzer as AN

pathtoJSON = "C:\\Tools"

class Second(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        
        self.button = QPushButton('1', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.analyze)
        self.button.resize(self.button.sizeHint())
        self.button.move(167, 220)

        self.text = "2".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,15)

        self.textbox1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox1.move(55, 20)
        self.textbox1.resize(300,20)

        self.text = "3".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,65)

        self.textbox2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox2.move(150, 70)
        self.textbox2.resize(100,20)

        self.text = "4".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,115)

        self.textbox3 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox3.move(150, 120)
        self.textbox3.resize(200,20)

        self.text = "5".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,165)

        self.textbox4 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox4.move(150, 170)
        self.textbox4.resize(200, 20)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 260)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Settings')

    def analyze(self):
        #This command here generates a file from the following inputs from Second Window. This file appears at the following path in the variable pathtoJSON.
#        AN.checkStream(self.textbox1.text(), self.textbox2.text(), self.textbox3.text(), self.textbox4.text())

        global urlBox
        urlBox = self.textbox1.text()

        global durationBox
        durationBox = self.textbox2.text()

        global json_filename_box
        json_filename_box = self.textbox3.text()

        global playlistBox
        playlistBox =  self.textbox4.text()

        f = open(pathtoJSON + "\\" + str(self.textbox3.text()) + ".txt")   

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self): 
        #The file should be displayed in this textEdit box  
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        #This action does nothing for now.
        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Run with configuration', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Run with file')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        #This is supposed to ask you for your settings of the file and then when you pressed the button. It analyzes the file with the analyzer script and is supposed to grab the file 
        singleURL = QAction('Input URL', self)
        singleURL.setStatusTip('Analyze with a single URL')        
        singleURL.triggered.connect(self.showSettings)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)
        fileMenu.addAction(singleURL)

        self.runURL = Second(self)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('HLS Automation')
        self.showMaximized()

    def showSettings(self):     
        file = self.runURL.show()

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')
        if fname[0]:
            f = open(fname[0], 'r')
            with f:
                data = f.read()
                self.textEdit.setText(data)  


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There are two different windows. The Second Main Window is accessed by clicking on "Input URL". In this window, you can run the Analyzer (This script is was created by me). So the idea is to run the analyzer script. It generates a file after running and is stored in the directory indicated by pathtoJSON. It does that fine but so far I am only able to get the save the file into a variable. Also that variable is in the Second Main Window function.

So can someone please explain to me how I can get the file from the Second Window and display it on the textEdit portion in Main Window? Am I doing something wrong in my code that prevents me from doing that?

Comment: show analyzer.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, 
        QApplication, QWidget, QDialog, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QLabel, QGridLayout, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

#import analyzer as AN

pathtoJSON = "C:\\Tools"

class Second(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        
        self.button = QPushButton('1', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.analyze)
        self.button.resize(self.button.sizeHint())
        self.button.move(167, 220)

        self.text = "2".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,15)

        self.textbox1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox1.move(55, 20)
        self.textbox1.resize(300,20)

        self.text = "3".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,65)

        self.textbox2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox2.move(150, 70)
        self.textbox2.resize(100,20)

        self.text = "4".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,115)

        self.textbox3 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox3.move(150, 120)
        self.textbox3.resize(200,20)

        self.text = "5".format(0, 0)
        self.label = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label.move(20,165)

        self.textbox4 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox4.move(150, 170)
        self.textbox4.resize(200, 20)

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 260)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.setWindowTitle('Settings')

    def analyze(self):
        #This command here generates a file from the following inputs from Second Window. This file appears at the following path in the variable pathtoJSON.
#        AN.checkStream(self.textbox1.text(), self.textbox2.text(), self.textbox3.text(), self.textbox4.text())

        global urlBox
        urlBox = self.textbox1.text()

        global durationBox
        durationBox = self.textbox2.text()

        global json_filename_box
        json_filename_box = self.textbox3.text()

        global playlistBox
        playlistBox =  self.textbox4.text()

        f = open(pathtoJSON + "\\" + str(self.textbox3.text()) + ".txt")   

        # +++
        self.ex = Example()
        self.ex.showFile(f)
        self.ex.show()
        self.close()          



class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self): 
        #The file should be displayed in this textEdit box  
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        #This action does nothing for now.
        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Run with configuration', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Run with file')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        #This is supposed to ask you for your settings of the file and then when you pressed the button. It analyzes the file with the analyzer script and is supposed to grab the file 
        singleURL = QAction('Input URL', self)
        singleURL.setStatusTip('Analyze with a single URL')        
        singleURL.triggered.connect(self.showSettings)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)
        fileMenu.addAction(singleURL)

        self.runURL = Second(self)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('HLS Automation')
        self.showMaximized()

    def showSettings(self):     
        file = self.runURL.show()
        self.hide()                                          # +++

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')
        if fname[0]:
            f = open(fname[0], 'r')
            with f:
                data = f.read()
                self.textEdit.setText(data)  

    # +++
    def showFile(self, f):    
        with f:
            data = f.read()
            self.textEdit.setText(data)         


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So let me see if I'm an understanding this. So in the analyze function, are you recalling the Example window so that way you can display the information there? Also If you have to do that, then what the ex = Example() do at the bottom of the code?

Comment: Yes, in class Second you do everything you need, including calling analyze. When you need to transfer data from the Second window to display and other calculations, you create the Example class constructor and pass the data to the desired method of this class for display or further processing.